# Insert points to PostGIS using a function

Tags: python, postgis, psycopg2

I am trying to insert points geometry into PostGIS database. Well I tried to use a function just to read point coordinates and attributes and save them in a table in PostGIS. It works for attributes but not for geometry. This is my python code:

```py
insert(id, Height, X, Y)
....
def insert(gid,height, X, Y):
   gid=str(gid)
   connection = psycopg2.connect(host='', dbname='postgres',   user='', password='')     
    cur = connection.cursor()
   cur.execute ("""INSERT INTO gronkarta.test5 (gid, height, geom) VALUES (""" + gid + """,""" + str(height) + ""","""+ST_GeomFromText('POINT(X Y)', 3008)+""");""")
```

Comment: I used Python for this code.

Comment: Use something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python. There is no need to build up a string like that.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I changed the code like this:                                  cur.execute ("INSERT INTO gronkarta.test5 (gid, height, geom) VALUES  (gid, str(height), ST_GeomFromText('POINT(X Y)', 3008))")      Error:                                                                                               There is a column named "gid" in table "test5", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.

Comment: is gid an autonumber column?  If so, then just leave that column out and let the database assign the id:  cur.execute ("INSERT INTO gronkarta.test5 (height, geom) VALUES (str(height), ST_GeomFromText('POINT(X Y)', 3008))")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something more like this would be better, IMO. Creating the connection is more expensive, you should do that earlier in the program and pass it in. As noted by a commenter, you shouldn't compose SQL strings using string concatenation, you should use placeholders for more secure use of the database.

```
def db_insert_point(conn, height, x, y):
    sql = "INSERT INTO gronkarta.test5 (height, geom) VALUES (%s, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(%s, %s), 3008))"
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute(sql, (height, x, y))
    conn.commit()
```

If you're running `db_insert_point()` in a tight loop, you'll want to call `conn.commit()` at the end of the loop, rather than once per insert, for performance purposes, so you could move the commit outside the function in that case, to get multiple inserts into a single transaction.